# STL container with iterators to itself: set vs unordered_set

Tags: c++, templates, stl, unordered-set

I would like to create a container with data that includes iterator to the container itself. Simplified code is below. It works for most STL containers (`vector`, `set` etc) but doesn't compile for `unordered_set` with some mysterious compilation errors inside the check for hash requirements.

```
#include <set>
#include <unordered_set>

template <class C, class T>
struct rebind {};

template <class T0, class T>
struct rebind<std::set<T0>, T> {
    using type = std::set<T>;
};

template <class T0, class T>
struct rebind<std::unordered_set<T0>, T> {
    using type = std::unordered_set<T>;
};

template <class C>
class wrapped_iterator;

template <class C>
using twisted_container = typename rebind<C, wrapped_iterator<C>>::type;

template <class C>
class wrapped_iterator : public twisted_container<C>::iterator {
    size_t key() const { return reinterpret_cast<std::uintptr_t>(std::addressof(**this)); }
    bool operator < (const wrapped_iterator& other) const { return key() < other.key(); }
    bool operator == (const wrapped_iterator& other) const { return key() == other.key(); }
};

namespace std {

template <class C>
struct hash<wrapped_iterator<C>> {
    size_t operator()(wrapped_iterator<C> it) const {
        return it.key();
    }
};

}

int main() {
    twisted_container<std::set<int>> a;
    twisted_container<std::unordered_set<int>> b;  // This doesn't compile!
    return 0;
}
```

clang error:

```
<source>:24:59: error: no type named 'iterator' in 'std::unordered_set<wrapped_iterator<std::unordered_set<int, std::hash<int>, std::equal_to<int>, std::allocator<int> > >, std::hash<wrapped_iterator<std::unordered_set<int, std::hash<int>, std::equal_to<int>, std::allocator<int> > > >, std::equal_to<wrapped_iterator<std::unordered_set<int, std::hash<int>, std::equal_to<int>, std::allocator<int> > > >, std::allocator<wrapped_iterator<std::unordered_set<int, std::hash<int>, std::equal_to<int>, std::allocator<int> > > > >'
    class wrapped_iterator : public twisted_container<C>::iterator {
                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~
```

gcc error:

```
<source>:24:11: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'twisted_container<std::unordered_set<int> >' {aka 'class std::unordered_set<wrapped_iterator<std::unordered_set<int> >, std::hash<wrapped_iterator<std::unordered_set<int> > >, std::equal_to<wrapped_iterator<std::unordered_set<int> > >, std::allocator<wrapped_iterator<std::unordered_set<int> > > >'}
     class wrapped_iterator : public twisted_container<C>::iterator {
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Am I trying to do something illegal? Is there a way to fix this error? Why is `unordered_set` special in this case? Is it the intended behavior or a bug in compilers implementation?

Comment: Be sure you know what operations invalidate iterators or you could have a nasty surprise in your near future.

Comment: I suspect you are running afoul of [**\[res.on.functions\]/2**](http://eel.is/c++draft/res.on.functions#2.5) "...the effects are undefined in the following cases: ... if an incomplete type (6.9) is used as a template argument when instantiating a template component, unless specifically allowed for that component." Neither `set` nor `unordered_set` specifically allow their element type to be incomplete, so your code exhibits undefined behavior for both. It may appear to work for `set` by accident - "seems to work" is one possible manifestation of undefined behavior.

Comment: Thank you very much, @IgorTandetnik. Now I think how to achieve what I need in the best standard-compliant way.